# Cloudformation template(JSON) for security group with 50 CIDR IPs (Ingress)

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating Cloud formation template for security group with ingress rule of over 50 CIDR IPs.
In Parameters, I used Commadelimited list for Multiple CIDR IPs.
Instead of creating seperate values in SecurityGroupIngress for each CIDR IP, Is it possible to include multiple  CidrIps in single code.

```
                    {
                        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                        "CidrIp" : "54.183.255.128/26",
                        "FromPort" : "443",
                        "ToPort" : "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                        "CidrIp" : "54.228.16.0/26", 
                        "FromPort" : "443",
                        "ToPort" : "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                        "CidrIp" :  "54.232.40.64/26", 
                        "FromPort" : "443",
                        "ToPort" : "443"
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                        "CidrIp" : "54.241.32.64/26", 
                        "FromPort" : "443",
                        "ToPort" : "443"
                    },
```

Template I want to use like below. But here I can able to get only 1 position CIDR IPs.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "HTTPS - Security Group",
    "Parameters": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "VPC where the Security Group will belong"
        },
        "Name": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Name Tag of the Security Group"
        },
        "DbSubnetIpBlocks": {
            "Description": "Comma-delimited list of CIDR blocks",
            "Type": "CommaDelimitedList"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "MySG": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": {
                    "Ref": "Description"
                },
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VPC"
                },
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "CidrIp": {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                "1",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "DbSubnetIpBlocks"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "FromPort": "443",
                        "ToPort": "443"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "SecurityGroupID": {
            "Description": "Security Group ID",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "MySG"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly its not possible. One security group (SG) rule applies to only one CIDR range.

There is a limit of [60](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups) rules in a SG, which you can request to be increased.

Although a single SG rule can refer to single CIDR, you can create CloudFormation [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to automatically create all these rules for you.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.  As there are over 50 CIDR IPs, the CF template will be so long if I include individual security group rule for each CIDR range.  So there is no use in defining Commadelimited in parameters.

Comment: @Gnay I updated the answer. If you will find it helpful, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated.